# How to normalize URL and disregard anything after the slash?

Tags: python, split, normalize

I have hundreds URLs which I want to normalise to a domain format -> domain.com, domain.ie, domain.de, domain.es etc. However I'm struggling to cover scenarios where there is a text after the '/' symbol.

I assume I need to add another if condition and find where is the first slash (/) in my URL string and then split with something similar to `u.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]`?

myCode so far:

```
from w3lib.url import url_query_cleaner
from url_normalize import url_normalize

urls = ['foo.com','www.foo.com/','foo.com/us','foo.com/ca/example-test/']


def canonical_url(u):
    u = url_normalize(u)
    u = url_query_cleaner(u,parameterlist = ['utm_source','utm_medium','utm_campaign','utm_term','utm_content'],remove=True)
    if u.startswith("http://"):
        u = u[7:]
    if u.startswith("https://"):
        u = u[8:]
    if u.startswith("www."):
        u = u[4:]
    if u.endswith("/"):
        u = u[:-1]
    return u

list(map(canonical_url,urls))
```

currently this returns:

```
['foo.com', 'foo.com', 'foo.com/us', 'foo.com/ca/example-test']
```

expected outcome:

```
['foo.com', 'foo.com', 'foo.com', 'foo.com']
```

Could someone help me with this please? thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use URLlib module in python

```
from urllib3.util import parse_url

urls = ['foo.com','www.foo.com/','foo.com/us','foo.com/ca/example-test/']
for url in urls:
   parsed_url = parse_url(url)
   host = parsed_url.host if not parsed_url.host.startswith('www.') else parsed_url.host.lstrip('www.')
```

Output will be as you expected.

Comment: Two points: 1) In [str.lstrip(chars)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=lstrip#str.lstrip) the `chars` argument is *"a string specifying the set of characters to be removed"*. That makes `str.lstrip('www.')` functionally equivalent to `lstrip('w.')`. 2) Using `lstrip('www.')` will incorrectly remove any leading 'w' characters from the host name. E.g.: `'www.weather.com'.lstrip('www.')` returns `'eather.com'`. Alternatively use: `host = parsed_url.host if not parsed_url.host.startswith('www.') else parsed_url.host.replace('www.', '', 1)`

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use urllib, which would do that for you, you can use split.

```
def canonical_url(u):
    u = url_normalize(u)
    u = url_query_cleaner(u,parameterlist = ['utm_source','utm_medium','utm_campaign','utm_term','utm_content'],remove=True)
    u = u.lstrip("http://")
    u = u.lstrip("https://")
    u = u.lstrip("www.")
    u = u.split('/')[0]  # get before first slash
    return u
```